# Heroku ACM Letsencrypt failure/waiting with rate limits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I have a site with multiple domains on Heroku, using Gandi for DNS. Using ACM on Heroku I got a lot of failures for the apex domains and tried again a few times - now my certs:info says "no SSL available" and certs:auto is stuck at "Waiting".

I also tried using different websites that are linked on letsencrypt and wanted to generate files and challenges, but did at some point get no challenge keys for my domains anymore.

Question: How can I check whether my requests are rate limited? Heroku does not show this info (just "waiting"). Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about Heroku ACM but Let's encrypt themselves have quite a lot of rate limits, see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/.

Comment: Open a support ticket and we can get to the bottom of this if it's still causing troubles.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBeynon. I think I already did but as my problem is solved for the next 11 months, I'll simply try again once the current cert needs to be renewed.